# Upgrade from 4.6.10 to 4.6.16 states DB already upgraded to 4.6.10

Tags: upgrade

Using WP 4.5.2 - We followed the steps to upgrade and when we ran step "4. Run the Upgrade script" we get the following error - Can not do this Database is already upgraded to 4.6.10.
Everything seems to work ok... but it still shows the version at 4.6.10.  Does this mean I have the 4.6.16 code but the DB is still at 4.6.10?   How do I get this completed?  I feel like I'm stuck in the middle somewhere?

Comment: can you confirm that old codebase has been sufficiently removed (not just renamed) so that there is no chance it is still referencing old files?

Comment: That must be it...  I just successfully did an upgrade in another test site which worked fine.   I'll have to check this one again later.  THANKS.

Comment: Gary - can you accept the answer then as that is what keeps the stackexchange gears oiled

Comment: Sorry for not responding.... I was able to upgrade the live...  We must have missed something... So yes we are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your old codebase has been sufficiently removed (not just renamed) so that there is no chance it is still referencing old files